# How to migrate existing React Native Project to React Native TVOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

using the React Native tvos, i want to focus tabs between.

I can create new project using react native tvos but unable convert the existing project. when i Try running npm i react-native@npm:react-native-tvos@latest for conversion,